# Passing array on Webservices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsmutableurlrequest

I am developing one app,in that i have used to send my contact numbers to the server through WebServices.Here i get the my contact numbers an array,and i send the contact array through webservices.Here below code,

```
NSString *myRequestString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"contact_numbers=%@",MobiileArray ];


NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString1 UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString1 length ] ];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myproject.in/myproject-contacts.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSError* error;
NSMutableArray* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                                         options:kNilOptions

                                                           error:&error];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
```

but the response is null ,any mistakes on my code? can you please suggest me Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: That might sound silly but are you sure your problem is on the client side? Maybe your webservice isn't returning what you would expect.

Comment: yes i did  many services through POST and GET methods but here i struggled @Zil

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution..!

Replace this lines of code

```
NSString *myRequestString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"contact_numbers=%@",MobiileArray ];
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString1 UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString1 length ] ];
```

//With this lines of code

```
//NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: MobiileArray forKey:@"contact_numbers"];

NSString* myRequestString1 = [MobiileArray JSONRepresentation];
NSData *myRequestData = [myRequestString1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

//put

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Check it...

Comment: thank you ,and contact_numbers is not a key , it is parameter for send data to webservices

Comment: I modified the answer...Check it now..!

Comment: same problem it's passing null @vidhyanand900

Comment: What is contact_numbers in your code...It is the parameter/key to pass ContactArray? Key is same as parameter...!

Comment: contact_numbers is a webservices parameter

Comment: Refer this link...!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968042/passing-parameters-to-a-json-web-service-in-objective-c